# How to store link information as an object property?

Tags: javascript

So, the problem is I know I can use window.open method to open a new window:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open

What I want to do is storing the link as an object property, for example, I would have:

```
objectwithlink {property1:"floor", property2:"tree", link:"http://www.google.com"};
```

So I tried to put objectwithlink.link inside the window.open () but it didn't work. Since " " are used javascript considers what is inside of " " as a text and does not access the link, if " " it doesn't work too. Any idea?

Comment: `but it didn't work` Post your (fuller) code if you want debugging help.

Comment: Ok it did work it was just I didn't write it properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way to do is, You just have to add that link variable which contain link as value in the below code.

```js
var obj = {property1:"floor", property2:"tree"};
obj['link'] = "http://www.fb.com";

console.log(obj);
```

But if you want to use that object's link then you can use as below.

```js
var obj = {property1:"floor", property2:"tree"};
obj['link'] = "http://www.fb.com";
console.log(obj);
    
let link = obj.link ;
console.log(link);
window.open(link);
```

I hope, i did understood your question proper.